# create view in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-migration, sql-view

I have several tables and two functions in the PostgreSQL database.
I migrated the SQL Server database to the PostgreSQL database.
Now, I want to create a view which gets data from multiple tables.
That works fine in the SQL Server but in PostgreSQL not works because has different schemas and syntax.
Does anyone know how to create a view in PostgreSQL?
How can I convert SQL Server view to PostgreSQL?
I am new to PostgreSQL and don't know much about it.
so,here is my `"payment_status"` view code

```
 ALTER VIEW "PAYMENT_STATUS" AS 
SELECT        dbo.PAYMENTS.ID, dbo.PAYMENTS.ACADEMIC_YEAR, dbo.PAYMENTS.BRANCH, dbo.PAYMENTS.MEMBER_ID, dbo.STUDENTS.FULL_NAME, dbo.STUDENTS.MOBILE, dbo.STUDENTS.EMAIL, dbo.PAYMENTS.STD, 
                         dbo.PAYMENTS.FEE_TYPE, dbo.PAYMENTS.INSTALLMENT, dbo.PAYMENTS.AMOUNT, dbo.PAYMENTS.LATE_FEE_RATE, dbo.PAYMENTS.LATE_FEE_LIMIT, dbo.PAYMENTS.START_DATE, dbo.PAYMENTS.DUE_DATE, 
                         dbo.PAYMENTS.EXPIRY_DATE, dbo.PAYMENTS.REMARKS, ISNULL(TRANSACTIONS.ID, - 1) AS TXID, ISNULL(TRANSACTIONS.TXN_ID, '') AS TXN_ID, ISNULL(TRANSACTIONS.TXN_DATE, '') AS TXN_DATE, 
                         ISNULL(TRANSACTIONS.TOTAL_AMOUNT, dbo.PAYMENTS.AMOUNT + dbo.CalcDue(dbo.PAYMENTS.DUE_DATE, dbo.PAYMENTS.LATE_FEE_RATE, dbo.PAYMENTS.LATE_FEE_LIMIT)) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT, 
                         ISNULL(TRANSACTIONS.TOTAL_LATE_FEE_AMOUNT, dbo.CalcDue(dbo.PAYMENTS.DUE_DATE, dbo.PAYMENTS.LATE_FEE_RATE, dbo.PAYMENTS.LATE_FEE_LIMIT)) AS TOTAL_LATE_FEE_AMOUNT, 
                         ISNULL(TRANSACTIONS.PAYMENT_MODE, '') AS PAYMENT_MODE, ISNULL(TRANSACTIONS.REF_NO, '') AS REF_NO, ISNULL(TRANSACTIONS.REF_DETAILS, '') AS REF_DETAILS, 
                         ISNULL(TRANSACTIONS.TECH_RESPONSE_F1, '') AS TECH_RESPONSE_F1, ISNULL(TRANSACTIONS.TECH_RESPONSE_F2, '') AS TECH_RESPONSE_F2, ISNULL(TRANSACTIONS.REMARKS, '') AS TX_REMARKS, 
                         ISNULL(TRANSACTIONS.STATUS, 'DUE') AS STATUS, ISNULL(TRANSACTIONS.FINANCIAL_INSTITUTE, '') AS FINANCIAL_INSTITUTE, ISNULL(TRANSACTIONS.CREATED_BY, dbo.PAYMENTS.CREATED_BY) 
                         AS TX_CREATED_BY, ISNULL(TRANSACTIONS.CREATED_ON, dbo.PAYMENTS.CREATED_ON) AS TX_CREATED_ON, ISNULL(TRANSACTIONS.MODIFIED_BY, dbo.PAYMENTS.MODIFIED_BY) AS TX_MODIFIED_BY, 
                         ISNULL(TRANSACTIONS.MODIFIED_ON, dbo.PAYMENTS.MODIFIED_ON) AS TX_MODIFIED_ON, dbo.PAYMENTS.CREATED_BY, dbo.PAYMENTS.CREATED_ON, dbo.PAYMENTS.MODIFIED_BY, 
                         dbo.PAYMENTS.MODIFIED_ON , ISNULL(TRANSACTIONS.ERPStatus, '') AS TX_ERPStatus
FROM            dbo.PAYMENTS INNER JOIN
                         dbo.STUDENTS ON dbo.PAYMENTS.MEMBER_ID = dbo.STUDENTS.MEMBER_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         (SELECT * FROM dbo.TRANSACTIONS WHERE STATUS!='REVERSED') AS TRANSACTIONS ON dbo.PAYMENTS.ID = TRANSACTIONS.PAYMENT_ID ;
```

Comment: To create a view you use [`create view`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html)

Comment: SQL means ms sql server

Comment: "but in PostgreSQL not works because has different schemas" And why do you think that we know the schema names that you use? And you could create a schema "dbo" in PostgreSQL and use this one for all your tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I got the solution and this is how I created the view in postgresql.

```
CREATE or REPLACE VIEW "payment_status" AS  SELECT payments.id,
payments.academic_year,
payments.branch,
payments.member_id,
students.full_name,
students.mobile,
students.email,
payments.std,
payments.fee_type,
payments.installment,
payments.amount,
payments.late_fee_rate,
payments.late_fee_limit,
payments.start_date,
payments.due_date,
payments.expiry_date,
payments.remarks,
COALESCE(transactions.id, ('-1'::integer)::bigint) AS txid,
COALESCE(transactions.txn_id, ''::text) AS txn_id,
COALESCE(transactions.txn_date, (NULL::date)::timestamp with time zone) AS txn_date,
COALESCE(transactions.total_amount, (payments.amount + calc_due((payments.due_date)::date, payments.late_fee_rate, payments.late_fee_limit))) AS total_amount,
COALESCE(transactions.total_late_fee_amount, calc_due((payments.due_date)::date, payments.late_fee_rate, payments.late_fee_limit)) AS total_late_fee_amount,
COALESCE(transactions.payment_mode, ''::text) AS payment_mode,
COALESCE(transactions.ref_no, ''::text) AS ref_no,
COALESCE(transactions.ref_details, ''::text) AS ref_details,
COALESCE(transactions.tech_response_f1, ''::text) AS tech_response_f1,
COALESCE(transactions.tech_response_f2, ''::text) AS tech_response_f2,
COALESCE(transactions.remarks, ''::text) AS tx_remarks,
COALESCE(transactions.status, 'DUE'::text) AS status,
COALESCE(transactions.financial_institute, ''::text) AS financial_institute,
COALESCE(transactions.created_by, payments.created_by) AS tx_created_by,
COALESCE(transactions.created_on, payments.created_on) AS tx_created_on,
COALESCE(transactions.modified_by, payments.modified_by) AS tx_modified_by,
COALESCE(transactions.modified_on, payments.modified_on) AS tx_modified_on,
payments.created_by,
payments.created_on,
payments.modified_by,
payments.modified_on,
COALESCE(transactions.erpstatus, ''::text) AS tx_erpstatus
FROM ((payments
 JOIN students ON ((payments.member_id = students.member_id)))
 LEFT JOIN ( SELECT transactions_1.id,
        transactions_1.txn_id,
        transactions_1.txn_date,
        transactions_1.payment_id,
        transactions_1.total_amount,
        transactions_1.total_late_fee_amount,
        transactions_1.payment_mode,
        transactions_1.ref_no,
        transactions_1.ref_details,
        transactions_1.tech_response_f1,
        transactions_1.tech_response_f2,
        transactions_1.remarks,
        transactions_1.status,
        transactions_1.financial_institute,
        transactions_1.created_by,
        transactions_1.created_on,
        transactions_1.modified_by,
        transactions_1.modified_on,
        transactions_1.erpstatus
       FROM transactions transactions_1
      WHERE (transactions_1.status <> 'REVERSED'::text)) transactions ON ((payments.id = transactions.payment_id))); ;
```

Comment: `('-1'::integer)::bigint` can be simplified to `-1::bigint` and `(NULL::date)::timestamp with time zone)` can be simplified to `null::timestamptz` and `'DUE'::text` can be simplified to 'DUE'` .